Incomplete integral of confluent hypergeometric function
I would like to prove the following: if $a,b,c > 0$, $0<x<1$, $y>0$, then,
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(b)}\int_0^{\infty} s^{b-1} e^{-s} \,\mbox{$ {}_1\mathrm{F}_1 (a\,; c\,; x s + y\hspace{1pt})$}\hspace{1pt}ds =  \mbox{$\mathrm{\Phi}_1\big(a,b,c,x,y\hspace{1pt}) $}
$$
where $\Phi_1$ is the first Humbert series function, or confluent hypergeometric function of two variables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series). I am particularly interested in the case $c < a$.
If $c > a$, we can evaluate this integral by first representing ${}_1\textrm{F}_1$ as an integral,
$$
\mbox{$ {}_1\mathrm{F}_1 (a\,; c\,;x s+y\hspace{1pt})$}\hspace{1pt} = \frac{1}{B(a,c-a)}\int_{0}^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1} e^{(xs+y)\hspace{0.5pt}t} dt
$$
Then, switching the order of integrals, we evaluate,
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(b)}\int_0^{\infty} s^{b-1} e^{-s} e^{x\hspace{1pt} t  s}\,ds= (1-x\hspace{1pt}t)^{-b}
$$
and then,
$$
\frac{1}{B(a,c-a)}\int_{0}^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1} (1-x\hspace{1pt}t)^{-b} e^{y\hspace{0.5pt}t} dt =  \mbox{$\mathrm{\Phi}_1\big(a,b,c,x,y \hspace{1pt}\big) $}
$$
This integral arises in the context of linear mixed effects models in statistics. In the relevant case, $c < a$, so the integral representation of $_1\mathrm{F}_1$ is not valid. Using the series representation doesn't seem tractable. Any ideas on how to verify this integral representation of the Humbert function in general?

The notation in the OP was changed in a recent edit, this answer refers to the integral:
$$I = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^{\infty} s^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta s} \,\mbox{$ {}_1\mathrm{F}_1 (a\,; c\,; b s + d\hspace{1pt})$}\hspace{1pt}ds.$$

If $d=0$ we can use formula 7.522.9 of Gradshteyn & Ryzhik,

hence
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^{\infty } s^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta s} \, _1F_1(a;c;b s) \, ds=\beta^{-\alpha}  \, _2F_1\left(a,\alpha;c;b/\beta\right),\;\;\alpha,\beta>0,\;\;\beta>b,$$
irrespective of whether $c$ is smaller or larger than $a$.

Yes, I am aware. It's titled "incomplete integral" because d is non-zero.
